# Why is the book of Jasher considered to be non-canonical even though the book is referenced in Joshua 10:13?

Tags: canonicity

Why is the book of Jasher considered to be non-canonical even though the book is referenced in Joshua 10:13?  I always hear the phrase, "must be inspired by God", but all our texts are just visions/voice of God being heard.  How do we know any of the prophets are truly prophets?  Why is Jasher not one of these?

The main argument that I feel holds water is that Jesus refers to the books and the authenticity of a person being a prophet.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please edit your question and include a specific biblical text that you find troubling, as per the guidelines of BH, so that hermeneutical methods can be applied. As it is now, it is hard to know which text you are referring to in this question. Thanks.

Comment: What "Book of Jasher"?  There are several by that name?

Comment: Cf. Psalm 69:28.

Comment: See [non-canonical books referenced in the Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-canonical_books_referenced_in_the_Bible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that the Book of Jashar, or Sefer HaYashar, ספר הישר, is lost now*, and was already lost at the time of canonization, whether Christian or Jewish, and what is lost cannot be canonical.

The Biblical references to it are:

1. [II Samuel 1:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%201%3A18&version=KJV)
2. [Joshua 10:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joshua%2010%3A13&version=KJV)

The works that we do have that go by the name of Book of Jashar, or Sefer HaYashar are:

1. A collection of sayings of the Jewish Babylonian sages from the first through the third centuries that does not purport to be the Biblical *Book of Jashar*
2. A commentary on the Pentateuch by the 12th-century [Abraham ibn Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) that does not purport to be the Biblical *Book of Jashar*
3. [Rabbeinu Tam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbeinu_Tam)'s 12th-century treatise on Jewish ritual and ethics that does not purport to be the Biblical *Book of Jashar*
4. Abraham ben Samuel Abulafia's 13th-sentury kabalistic treatise that does not purport to be the Biblical *Book of Jashar*
5. A midrashic collection from the 16th century that does not purport to be the Biblical *Book of Jashar*
6. An 18th century work **that does purport** to be the Book of Jashar referenced in the OT, by the London printer and Christian religious radical [Jacob Ilive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Ilive)
7. [Benjamin Rosenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Rosenbaum)'s fictional work published in 2002

The latter work by Benjamin Rosenbaum is part of a recent trend by modern authors to write fictional "Biblical" books that present alternative views (the "un-offical versions") of Biblical stories or history. Another example is David Grossman's *Lion's Honey*, that gives an alternative view of the life of Samson.

---

<sup>*Another way of stating this is to say that the *Book of Jashar* has not yet been found. And if it were to be found, re-opening the canon would be an issue in itself.</sup>

Comment: Great and comprehensive list of "the book of Jasher" through history. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that the question of canon is effectively answered by any individual individually and or by any given group corporately. We've no history of any universally recognized individual or group within either Judaism or Christianity that has been or is positioned to do so. In a word, the word is what you are willing to hear. A fragment of whichever Jasher one finds can be canonized by anyone's yard stick whether or not anyone else is willing to be measured by it. Good question.